# Properly use NoOptionsMessage in react-select to change the "no options" text

Tags: reactjs, react-select

I am trying to change the "No options" message in `react-select`? I was able to do this with the following code

```
<AsyncSelect 
    styles={customStyles} 
    components={{ DropdownIndicator: () => null, IndicatorSeparator: () => null, NoOptionsMessage: () => "test" }} 
    className="form-control firm-search"
    cacheOptions
    defaultOptions
    value={selectedValue}
    getOptionLabel={e => e.name}
    getOptionValue={e => e.path}
    loadOptions={loadOptions}
    onInputChange={handleInputChange}
    onChange={handleChange}
    placeholder='test ...'
/>
```

The problem is that the text is not styled anymore. Is it possible to change the text but keep the default style? If not, is it then possible to apply CSS to the new text?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There are two ways to style the custom component. You can pass a style object to `styles` prop or create a new custom component.

Following code shows both approaches.

```
import React from "react";
import "./style.css";
import Select, { components } from "react-select";

const msgStyles = {
  background: "skyblue",
  color: "white"
};

const NoOptionsMessage = props => {
  return (
    <components.NoOptionsMessage {...props}>
      <span className="custom-css-class">Text</span> 
    </components.NoOptionsMessage>
  );
};

const CustomNoOptionsMessage = () => {
  return (
    <Select
      isClearable
      components={{ NoOptionsMessage }}
      styles={{ noOptionsMessage: base => ({ ...base, ...msgStyles }) }}
      isSearchable
      name="color"
      options={[]}
    />
  );
};

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <CustomNoOptionsMessage />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Here you can find the working code:https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-lejn8c?file=src/App.js

Answer (score 12):

Another way to do this:

```
<AsyncSelect
  isClearable
  defaultOptions
  cacheOptions
  defaultOptions
  value={selectedValue}
  getOptionLabel={e => e.name}
  getOptionValue={e => e.path}
  loadOptions={loadOptions}
  onInputChange={handleInputChange}
  onChange={handleChange}
  noOptionsMessage={({inputValue}) => !inputValue ? noOptionsText : "No results found"} 
/>
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a documented way of doing this: https://react-select.com/components

You can define your own `NoOptionMessage` component:

```js
import { components } from 'react-select';

const NoOptionsMessage = props => {
  return (
     <components.NoOptionsMessage {...props}>
        Test…
     </components.NoOptionsMessage>
  );
};
```

In the `components` module you can access every native implementation so you don't need to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: how do we keep the placeholder set even when no options?

Answer (score 1):

It's work for me:

```
<Select 
 placeholder="Choose something..."
 noOptionsMessage={() => "No more options"}
 value={value}
 options={options} 
 onChange={onChangeHandle} 
 theme={(theme) => ({
   ...theme,
   borderRadius: 10,
   colors: {
   ...theme.colors,
      text: '#e04e39',
      primary25: '#e04e39',
      primary: '#da8a7e',
      },
 })}
 />
```